# Laravel 4 css & javascript link using {{ HTML}}

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am beginner  in Laravel 4 and I have include css file using HTML class but it's not working so please help me.
My code is  :-

In view :- model_window.php

```
<?php HTML::style('css/style.css'); ?>

<a href="#openModal"><input  type="submit" value="show" name=""show_button></a>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
   <div>
      <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
      <h2>Modal Box</h2>

   </div>
</div>
```

my css  file :- in public -> css -> style.css

```
.modalDialog:target {
                  opacity:1;
                  pointer-events: auto;
                   }

     .modalDialog > div {
                width: 400px;
                position: relative;
                margin: 10% auto;
                padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
                border-radius: 10px;
                background: #fff;
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
                background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
                 }
```

Comment: you are missing `echo` <?php echo HTML::style('css/style.css'); ?>

Comment: Are you using Blade templating? if yes then you have to use `.blade.php` extension

Answer (score 6):

you can rename your file to such as index.blade.php second of that must be have blade and you can  simply use:

```
    {{ HTML::style('public/css/index.css') }}
    {{ HTML::script('public/js/jquery.pnotify.min.js') }}
```

Comment: I don't think `public` folder should be here. Rather, Laravel's `public` folder should be the web root. And you should use `{{ HTML::style('css/index.css') }}` to reference resources.

Answer (score 5):

you must to put files into public directory and then can easily use

```
<?php echo HTML::style('css/style.css'); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your view is invalid. You need to include link to .css file between  tags.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <?=HTML::style('link/to/style.css')?>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#openModal"><input  type="submit" value="show" name=""show_button></a>

    <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
       <div>
          <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
          <h2>Modal Box</h2>

       </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, it will work.

Comment: What is the output of the view file? Use http://jsfiddle.net/, provide HTML markup and CSS styles

Comment: @Andreyco why the view is invalid? This `<?php echo HTML::style('css/style.css'); ?>` just works perfectly.

Comment: @Andreyco: He's not using blade, so blade syntax won't work here.

Comment: @cuewizchris the question title "Laravel 4 css & javascript link using {{ HTML}}" says, he is! Is it a problem (and the reason for downvote) to rewrite Blade syntax to non-blade syntax? I think, my answer is perfectly valid, but I corrected the answer to use not blade syntax, to please everyone

Comment: @TryingTobemyself view file is invalid beacause of 2 reasons: **1:** OP is not echoing the output of `HTML::style('css/style.css')`. Modifying to `echo HTML::style('css/style.css')` or `{{ HTML::style('css/style.css') }}` would. **2:** OP is placing `<link/> outside of <head> tags

Comment: @Andreyco: The title says a different thing, right, but his view file is named `model_window.php`. So apparently, blade is NOT enabled in his case.

Comment: @Andreyco you should have mention that in the answer, just correcting OP's code is not good, atleast OP should know what his mistake is

Answer (score 3):

You always have to include your CSS files in the `<head>` section of your HTML. That's why your styles aren't applied.

And the relevant line should be:

```
<?php echo HTML::style('css/style.css'); ?>
```